# Passing parameters to custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, oop, uitableview, swift

I'm registering a custom cell from a Nib in the TableViewController

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

but my CustomCell has IBAction methods that need access to the tableView itself and the fetchedResultsController. How do I pass those parameters in a clean way to the CustomCell?

Setting those things in:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
   return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell 
}
```

doesn't seem to be the clean way to me..?

Comment: oo you are right, stupid me :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell really shouldn't know anything about the table view or the fetchedResultsController. One way to do this is to add your actions in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and make the controller the target.

Another option is to have the action methods in the custom cell class, and have them call delegate protocol methods that you create in the cell class. Have the controller set itself as the delegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: How it get worked..? I didn't understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the class that is responsible for Custom Cell IBAction example

```
IBAction Func enterKeyButton (sender: AnyObject) {
    println(sender)
}
```

and in tableview implement the method and that's the way of the cause medot Custom Cell

```
func tableView (tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.enterKeyButton ("hello")

    return cell
}
```

I hope I helped you!